# Grade Viewing of Student in php

Tags: php

**Hello, I am new in php**
I am making an Web Based Online Grading System, my problem is I want to view my grade as a *Student*
When i logged in as a Student it displays all the data from the grades that i uploaded.

```
                      <?php
                      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','grade') or die(mysqli_error());
                      $query = "Select * from grades where sID <= ID";
                      $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $studentid = $row['StudentID'];
                             $firstname = $row['StudentName'];
                             $subject = $row['Subject'];
                             $desc = $row['Description'];
                              $first = $row['Prelim'];
                              $second = $row['Midterm'];
                             $third = $row['PreFinal'];
                             $fourth = $row['Final'];
                             $final = $row['Equi'];
                             $remark = $row['Remarks'];
                    ?>
                      <td> <?php echo $subject ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $desc ?> </td>

                      <td> <?php echo $first ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $second ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $third ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $fourth ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $final ?> </td>
                      <td> <?php echo $remark ?> </td>
                    </tr>
                      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  will want to change your query to use `WHERE` in relation to `StudentID` (ore perhaps `sID`?? not sure based on your query statement):

```
"SELECT * FROM `grades` where `StudentID` = ?"
```

`?` being the ID value which may need to be bound, if it's numeric and you check that it is before using it in the query may not need binding but binding parameters is safer.

Presumably, you have stored the `StudentID` in a session or cookie after the user logs in, so that is where you would draw that value from.